# You would think that someone who was in the military

Tags: tense, would, hypothetical

Imagine that John is in the military, but he's living a totally undisciplined life. John's friend says:

(1) You would think that someone who was in the military would be more disciplined.

Now, imagine that John was in the military at some point of time, but no longer now, and he's living a totally undisciplined life. John's friend says:

(2) You would think that someone who had been in the military would be more disciplined.

Are (1) and (2) correct in the contexts given?

Comment: Are the sentences meant to be backshifted (for example, do they occur as part of a narrative passage which is written in the past tense)? If they are *not* intended to be backshifted, "was" should be "is" in (1), and "had been" should be "was" in (2).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to add more details. What context are you using the sentences in: a narrative, reported speech (which can also be backshifted), or an exact quote of what John's friend actually said? Is the thing you're unsure about the choice of tense in each sentence? If so, why do you think the tenses you picked (simple past in 1 and past perfect in 2) are or aren't correct?

Comment: The only answer right now is "Sure, they are." This question does not meet the on-topic requirements right now. To be on-topic, please use the "Edit" button to tell more about why you had concerns about these.